# android chart in the same page as other stuff

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, charts

I am trying to add a chart to the screen, that also has some more data, like this:
[image]

 However, the chart library I am using ([achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/)) currently, sends the chart info as an intent to an 

activity that starts in a new screen. Is there a library that displays chart as a child of a layout(eg. LinearLayout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home) can be used in an arbitary layout.  Most of the demos are full screen but you can see what you do with the xml layout in the [quickstart](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart) tutorial.

Comment: let me check it out and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember that achartengine can do this too.  I think that one of the demo applications that you can [download](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-0.7.0-demo-source.zip&can=2&q=) from the site has this kind of functionality: `XYChartBuilder`.  Take a look at the source for that one and see if the approach will work for you.